# /bin/sh: 1: gdk-pixbuf-config: not found

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, gdkpixbuf

I am trying to compile a C/C++ program which is based on gdk-pixbuf, during compilation i get error "/bin/sh: 1: gdk-pixbuf-config: not found"

I got below packages currently, kindly guide, what i am missing? I am using Ubuntu 12.04, 32 bit

```
dpkg -l | grep libgdk
ii  libgdk-pixbuf2-ruby                    1.0.3-1build1                                       Transitional package for ruby-gdk-pixbuf2
ii  libgdk-pixbuf2-ruby1.8                 1.0.3-1build1                                       Transitional package for ruby-gdk-pixbuf2
ii  libgdk-pixbuf2-ruby1.8-dbg             1.0.3-1build1                                       Transitional package for ruby-gdk-pixbuf2-dbg
ii  libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0                     2.26.1-1                                            GDK Pixbuf library
ii  libgdk-pixbuf2.0-common                2.26.1-1                                            GDK Pixbuf library - data files
ii  libgdk-pixbuf2.0-dev                   2.26.1-1                                            GDK Pixbuf library (development files)
ii  libgdk-pixbuf2.0-doc                   2.26.1-1                                            GDK Pixbuf library (documentation)
ii  libgdkcutter-pixbuf-dev                1.1.7-1.1                                           Cutter Gdk-pixbuf support (Development files)
ii  libgdkcutter-pixbuf0                   1.1.7-1.1                                           Cutter Gdk-pixbuf support (Shared library)
```